# Assign Spring bean to field not managed by Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a configuration object that is managed by Spring. Let's call that object 'ConfigurationObject'. The configuration contained by that object I also want to make accessible, through delegation, in objects which I instantiate with the 'new' operator. Let's call these objects 'UserObject'. 
Would it then be acceptable to pass the configurationObject as an argument to the constructor of the UserObject and then assign it to a regular private field that is not managed by Spring? So that I can then use the ConfigurationObject to return configuration form the UserObject. See below for the story in code.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationObject {

   private final String configItem;

   public ConfigurationObject(@Value("${config.item}") final String configItem){
        this.configItem = configItem;
   }

   public String getConfigItem() {
     return configItem;
  }
}

public final class UserObject {

    private ConfigurationObject configurationObject;
    /* other properties */

    public UserObject(final ConfigurationObject configurationObject) {
       this.configurationObject = configurationObject;
    }

    public String getConfigItem(){
      return configurationObject.getConfigItem();
    }
}
```

Best regards,

Henk

Comment: you dont have any Bean configuration in your configuration class So why are you using @configuration ?

Comment: It is okay.Spring will also treat @Configuration as a spring bean by auto-scan

Comment: then why not @Component ...its not confusing ?

Comment: But if it really represent as an configuration concept (which I think most probably it is based on the class name and its field name) , using @Configuration expresses the intent of the class much more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Spring class using context from `ApplicationInitializer`:

```
ApplicationInitializer.getAppContext().getBean(ConfigurationObject.class);
```

Or create class to get Spring context using [ApplicationContextAware](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=18579463):

> ```
> @Component
> public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
>
>    private static ApplicationContext context;
>
>    public static UserService getUserService() {
>        return (UserService)context.getBean("userService");
>    }
>
>    @Override
>    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
>
>        // store ApplicationContext reference to access required beans later on
>        SpringContext.context = context;
>    }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is a very valid use-case. I often do it when I need to create an object which some of its properties are determined during the runtime which do not know upfront.

I would suggest creating a factory method on `ConfigurationObject` for creating an `UserObject`:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationObject {

   private final String configItem;

   public ConfigurationObject(@Value("${config.item}") final String configItem){
        this.configItem = configItem;
   }

   public String getConfigItem() {
     return configItem;
  }

   public UserObject createUserObject(){
     return new UserObject(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I indeed have factory class for creating the UserObjects, but your suggestion to put the factory method on the ConfigurationObject is cleaner.